# MySQL import and export problem

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I am trying to export a table from one database and import it into another. The table in question has a definition like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `mydb`.`people` (
  `id` BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

And I'm exporting it like this:

```
mysqldump -u root -pmypass -h x.x.x.x mydb people > /tmp/export.sql
```

And trying to import it like this:

```
mysql -u root  mydb < /tmp/export.sql
```

To which I get the error:

```
ERROR 1406 (22001) at line 1: Data too long for column 'id' at row 1
```

Looking at the file, It has exported the id as values like this:

```
'\0\0�\�\��DM�� �Ϥ6�'
```

Which seems to be interpreted as a string. Now, since I'm dealing with tremendous amounts of data and cannot go through it manually, is there a way I can fix the import/export to interpret this value as binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `--hex-blob`:

```
mysql> create database dbase;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> use dbase;
Database changed
mysql> create table hexhex ( id binary(16) );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into hexhex values (UNHEX('DEADBEEF'));
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from hexhex;
+------------------+
| id               |
+------------------+
| ޭ▒               |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> quit
Bye
root@ironforge:~# mysqldump --hex-blob -p dbase > dbase.sql
Enter password:
root@ironforge:~#
```

This produces `INSERT` statements in the format:

```
INSERT INTO `hexhex` VALUES (0xDEADBEEF000000000000000000000000);
```

.. which are import-safe.

Re-import it, and check it's right:

```
root@ironforge:~# mysql -p dbase < dbase.sql
Enter password:
root@ironforge:~# mysql -p dbase

mysql> use dbase;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed

mysql> select * from hexhex;
+------------------+
| id               |
+------------------+
| ޭ▒               |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select hex(id) from hexhex;
+----------------------------------+
| hex(id)                          |
+----------------------------------+
| DEADBEEF000000000000000000000000 |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```